# Pattern matching on regex matches

Tags: python

The official tutorial (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/#adding-a-ui-matching-objects) shows that you can use use objects with the new pattern matching syntax, so I wanted to use it with regex matches like this:

```py
import re

match re.match(r"^foo", "foobar"):
    case re.Match(span=(start, end), match=match):
        print(f"match: {match} ({start}-{end})")
    case _:
        print("no matches")
```

But the first case never executes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, I played a while with it. I suppose the problem is result of the following: first, you can't create `re.Match` instances (`re.Match(span=(0,3), match='foo') `
` Traceback (most recent call last): `
` File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> `
`TypeError: cannot create 're.Match' instances`), so they don't have ordinary `__init__`. Second, they don't define `__match_args__` explicitly. Unfortunately, `re` is c-module, so we can't examine direct python equivalent.

Comment: As far as I can see, `re.Match` doesn't define `__match_args__` which is required for the new `match` statement.

Comment: @md2perpe It isn't required! Try to define simple class without it and match against it. `class Car: def __init__(self, a=1): self.a = a`. Car instance will match properly. `match Car(3): case Car(a=a): print(a)` prints 3.

Comment: According to the [specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/#class-patterns) ("If only keywords are present /.../"), the object matched must have all the attributes named by the keywords. A `Match` object has no `match` attribute.

Comment: A thing that I realized is that `span` and `match` in `re.Match` instances are *methods* not attributes for some reason despite what the pretty-printed instance suggests. So I guess it really is not possible to directly use it with match statements without doing extra work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a wrapper to wrap the args you want, or even if you just want a non-none match, you can do that here.

```
 import re


class MatchWrap:
    __match_args__ = "string"

    def __init__(self, string, match: None):
        self.string = string
        self.match = match


def wrap_match(match):
    if match:
        return MatchWrap(match.string, match)
    else:
        return None


match wrap_match(re.match(r"^foo", "foobar")):
    case MatchWrap(string="foobar") as obj:
        print(f"match: {obj.match.string} ({obj.match.start()}-{obj.match.end()})")
    case _:
        print("no matches")
```

Comment: This works, but I was hoping that pattern matching can deal with match objects in a slightly cleaner and simpler way, but making wrapper classes isn't exactly what I wished for. But this answers the question, so I'll accept this answer for now.